# Change the position of jquery datepicker to the top

Tags: jquery, css, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I want to change the position of my datepicker a little to the top.

[This is my datepicker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VPbrZ.png)

This is my code inside the `jquery` css file:

```
.ui-datepicker {
    width: 20em;
    padding: .2em .2em 0;
    display: none;
    margin-left: 32em;
    z-index: 10;
}
```

I just want to shift the datepicker a little to the top, so that it aligns with the **Occupancy Date** text. How do I do that?

Comment: could you please paste your html file or else explain with some extra content.

Answer (score 1):

I would try a negative margin

```
margin-top: -10px;
```